# Change the look of a URL with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Is there a way to change the look of a url using angularJS without modifying my folder structure?

So for example on my local code. If I want to navigation to my website I'd use something like so:

http://localhost:8888/myproject/src/#/home/1212341212

The number at the end is a url parameter. Is there a way without changing the folder structure where instead you can just type in:

http://localhost:8888/home/1212341212

Or is there no way and I just have to move around my folder structure?

EDIT: Code provided:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/home/:tel', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/two', {
            templateUrl: 'views/twoOverLay.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/moreThanTwo', {
            templateUrl: 'views/moreThanTwoOverlay.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/blank', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main1.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home/1234567150'});
```

Comment: read $location docs regarding html5Mode

Comment: how did you set the route with `ui-router` could you provide the code ?

Comment: @Lorenzo Hey sorry i miss tagged. I'm just using $routeProvider. I did provide the code though :)

Answer (score 0):

//since you are using the hashbang mode you need to include the '#' in your url.This should work for you. No need to change your folder structure.

```
http://localhost:8888/#/home/1212341212
```

Comment: Or you can enable the html5 mode and use the urls without the '#'. In angular by default html5 mode is disabled.